# Are hashed passwords using Blowfish ready to use with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have hashed a password using:

```
<?php
$hashed_password = password_hash($password , PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
 ?>
```

But now, when I'm trying to add it to the database using the following code, the query fails:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user
          ( email, hashed_password, first_name, last_name, address, birthday,
          newsletter
          )
          VALUES
          ( '{$email}', '{$hashed_password}', '{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$address}',
           '{$birthdate}', '{$newsletter}'
          )";

    if($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query))
    {
      //Success!
      header("Location: login-page.php");
      exit;
    }
      else
      {
        //Display error Message.
        echo "<p>User creation failed.</p>";
      }
```

I get the echo that is down there. The $connection **is** included. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: what does the error says

Comment: I specified that the error I get is the echo; therefore the query returns void

Comment: Password hashes produce characters that may not be SQL safe. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a field in the database which I was not calling, **and that field did not have a default value**.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use PASSWORD_DEFAULT instead of PASSWORD_BCRYPT and make sure that field in a database for a password is set to 60 characters.

Try like this

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$hashed_password = password_hash($password , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO user ( email, hashed_password, first_name, last_name, address, birthday, newsletter )
      VALUES ( '$email', '$hashed_password', '$fname', '$lname', '$address', '$birthdate', '$newsletter' )") or die(mysqli_error());

if ($query)
{
    //Success!
    //header("Location: login-page.php");
    //exit();
    echo "<p>User creation success.</p>";
}
else
{
    //Display error Message.
    echo "<p>User creation failed.</p>";
}
```

Comment: In current versions of PHP, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT == PASSWORD_BCRYPT`.

Comment: Did u read documentation on php.net ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Of course. `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` can change with PHP versions, yes, but **currently** they are equivalent. Plus, unless OP is using `password_needs_rehash`, using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` won't do much besides hash *new* passwords with whatever updated algorithm internals decides to change `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` to in the future.

Comment: It's better for him to make it PASSWORD_DEFAULT so he doesn't need to edit a code in a future.

Comment: The way you wrote it, it sounded like you were suggesting not using PASSWORD_DEFAULT was the problem, instead of just a suggestion.

Comment: No problem was that most of peoples like him don't using error_report() to show them problem in query, code or other. I just suggested this for him because it's say on php.net that in the future and in php 7 option he using will not be supported.

Comment: No no i just wrote him a code with error reporting to see where is problem,  it was hes choice to chose of crypting password.